# How to compare the 3rd octet of an IP to the 3rd octet in an array of IP in bash

Tags: bash

Probably there is an easier way to do it but I have tried below and could not get it to work

```
ip=$1     #got the IP input 10.100.251.2
#broken into 4 octets via read
IFS="." read -r octet1 octet2 octet3 octet4 <<<"${ip}"

#the list to compare against
cat tmp_brd
10.100.123.255
10.100.127.255
10.100.239.255
10.100.255.255

#the list for the ouput which corresponds line by line to tmp_brd
cat tmp_sm
10.100.120.0
10.100.124.0
10.100.224.0
10.100.240.0

#the tmp_brd and tmp_sm arrays are collected from grep/awk the same file and each elements have 1 to 1 relation

mapfile -t sm_array <tmp_sm

mapfile -t brd_array <tmp_brd
brd_ln=${#brd_array[@]}

for ((i = 0; i < ${brd_ln}; i++)); do
    IFS="." read -r octet1$i octet2$i octet3$i octet4$i <<<"${brd_array[$i]}"
    if [[ $octet3 -lt $octet3$i ]]; then
        echo "${sm_array[$i]}" >>subnet
    fi
done
```

so basically ip=10.100.251.2 will match subnet=10.100.240.0 (from tmp_sm)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
Thanks

```
mapfile -t sm_array <tmp_sm

mapfile -t brd_array <tmp_brd
brd_ln=${#brd_array[@]}

for ((i = 0; i < ${brd_ln}; i++)); do
    IFS="." read -r oct1 oct2 oct3 oct4 <<<"${brd_array[$i]}"
    if [[ $octet3 -lt $oct3 ]]; then
        subnet=${sm_array[$i]}
        break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off using `ipcalc` for this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t network <tmp_sm
mapfile -t broadcast <tmp_brd

let l=${#network[@]}-1

declare -a networks
declare -a masks

for i in $(seq 0 $l)
do
    networks[$i]=$(ipcalc ${network[$i]} - ${broadcast[$i]} | tail -1)
    masks[$i]=$(echo ${networks[$i]} | cut -d/ -f2)
done

ip=10.100.251.2 # just hardcoding one for test

for i in $(seq 0 $l)
do
    echo "checking $ip against ${network[$i]} - ${broadcast[$i]} (${masks[$i]} bit mask)"
    n=$(ipcalc ${ip}/${masks[$i]} | grep ^Network | awk '{print $2}' )
    if [[ ${networks[$i]} == $n ]]
    then
        echo "$ip is in network ${networks[$i]}"
        ipcalc $ip/${masks[$i]}
        break;
    fi
done
```